# Error in C code. Will show up "No file"

Tags: c

I have problem with this code. When I gonna run it it'll show me "No File"

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main (argc, argv)
char *argv[];
{
    int fd;
    extern int errno;
    if (argc < 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "No file\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if ((fd = creat(argv[1], 0777))< 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"Cannot create file %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
            exit(1);
    case 0:
            close(1);
            dup(fd);
            close(fd);

            execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
            perror("Exec");
            break;
    default:
            wait(0);
            close(fd);


}
exit(0);
}
```

and will put out "warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'" - for all 5 exit.

Comment: You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: I don't understand the main declaration.

Comment: @MartinJames It's a K&R declaration, perfectly fine.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: And `<unistd.h>` for `close()`, `dup()` and `execl()`, and `<fcntl.h>` for `creat()`...

Comment: OP, how did you invoke the process?

Comment: @FUZxxl it looks weird..

Comment: @EOF true, but he didn't mention _these_ warnings.

Comment: @MartinJames: But you didn't find `extern int errno` weird? This code must be ancient.

Comment: @EOF well, I didn't get that far, but now you come to mention it...

Comment: @Michael Walz Everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinJames It is ancient, I am using ubuntu GNU Nano 2.2.6 compiler, so.. Yeah..

Comment: @user6200539 Are you sure that's your compiler? `nano` is a text editor.

Comment: Please don't use ancient K&R style declarations. The C programming community  switched to ANSI style declarations 25 years ago.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: AFAIK, K&R second edition already deprecated this. It's been "old" even before C89.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Since this is my assignment, I can't do much about using this .

Comment: @user6200539 God may have mercy with your soul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing two distinct problems:

> When you run the program it displays "No File"

This is because when you invoke the program, you aren't supplying a file name on the commande line, therefore `argc` is 1, hence the message.

> You get the warning: `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'` when you compile

This is because you didn't include `<stdlib.h>` which contains the declaration of `exit`.

You should also get more warnings due to the lack of including `<unistd.h>`, `<fcntl.h>` and `<wait.h>`.

---

**Side note**

You declare `extern int errno;` (without using btw). Instead of doing this, you should include .

---

**Side note 2**

You should consider "implicit declaration" warnings as errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "argc is 1" and why its not showing files?

Comment: @user6200539 read this [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).